# Infinity Norm calculation $\| \ln(x) - (\ln(3/2) + 2/3(x-3/2)) \|$

Tags: numerical-methods, normed-spaces

I have the following infinity norm: 
$$
\| \ln(x) - (\ln(3/2) + 2/3(x-3/2)) \|_\infty.
$$
Computing from [1,2].

I know that I can compute this in matlab and I get .072. However, how would one go about solving this by hand. I can't seem to find a good example that deals with infinity norm calculation. Thanks!

Comment: You need to give the range of $x$ over which you are computing the norm.

Comment: added in question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x) = \ln x - \ln{ 3 \over 2} + {2 \over 3} (x- { 3 \over 2} )$ is
concave and (by solving $f'(x) = 0$) has a maximum of zero at $x = {3 \over 2}$. Hence the minimum of $f$ occurs at the end points of the interval, in this
particular case, $x=1$, and we have
$|f(1)| = \ln {3 \over 2} - {1 \over 3} \approx 0.072 $.
Hence $\|f\|_\infty = \ln {3 \over 2} - {1 \over 3}$.